# Rpart equivalent to LM's se.fit

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, decision-tree, rpart

I have 2 regression models in R:

1. LM model in which I use the se.fit=true as follows:

   ```
   predict(my_model, newdata=data, se.fit=T)
   ```
2. Recursive Portioning Tree (using `rpart` package)

Unfortunately I don't have the `se.fit` option in `rpart`, and I'd like to calculate these values manually.

I do understand what the standard error means for a group of estimations (basically sum of mean squares) but what does it mean per each estimate separately as generated by `se.fit`?

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318409/how-to-prune-a-tree-in-r) helpful

Comment: @WojciechKsiążek, i didn't get how it may be helpful.. can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

After digging into that, I found out LM's se.fit is calculated in a little odd way. here is the implementation:

```
function (object, newdata, se.fit = FALSE, scale = NULL, df = Inf, 
          interval = c("none", "confidence", "prediction"), level = 0.95, 
          type = c("response", "terms"), terms = NULL, na.action = na.pass, 
          pred.var = res.var/weights, weights = 1, ...) 
{
  tt <- terms(object)
  if (!inherits(object, "lm")) 
    warning("calling predict.lm(<fake-lm-object>) ...")
  if (missing(newdata) || is.null(newdata)) {
    mm <- X <- model.matrix(object)
    mmDone <- TRUE
    offset <- object$offset
  }
  else {
    Terms <- delete.response(tt)
    m <- model.frame(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, 
                     xlev = object$xlevels)
    if (!is.null(cl <- attr(Terms, "dataClasses"))) 
      .checkMFClasses(cl, m)
    X <- model.matrix(Terms, m, contrasts.arg = object$contrasts)
    offset <- rep(0, nrow(X))
    if (!is.null(off.num <- attr(tt, "offset"))) 
      for (i in off.num) offset <- offset + eval(attr(tt, 
                                                      "variables")[[i + 1]], newdata)
    if (!is.null(object$call$offset)) 
      offset <- offset + eval(object$call$offset, newdata)
    mmDone <- FALSE
  }
  n <- length(object$residuals)
  p <- object$rank
  p1 <- seq_len(p)
  piv <- if (p) 
    qr.lm(object)$pivot[p1]
  if (p < ncol(X) && !(missing(newdata) || is.null(newdata))) 
    warning("prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading")
  beta <- object$coefficients
  predictor <- drop(X[, piv, drop = FALSE] %*% beta[piv])
  if (!is.null(offset)) 
    predictor <- predictor + offset
  interval <- match.arg(interval)
  if (interval == "prediction") {
    if (missing(newdata)) 
      warning("predictions on current data refer to _future_ responses\n")
    if (missing(newdata) && missing(weights)) {
      w <- weights.default(object)
      if (!is.null(w)) {
        weights <- w
        warning("assuming prediction variance inversely proportional to weights used for fitting\n")
      }
    }
    if (!missing(newdata) && missing(weights) && !is.null(object$weights) && 
        missing(pred.var)) 
      warning("Assuming constant prediction variance even though model fit is weighted\n")
    if (inherits(weights, "formula")) {
      if (length(weights) != 2L) 
        stop("'weights' as formula should be one-sided")
      d <- if (missing(newdata) || is.null(newdata)) 
        model.frame(object)
      else newdata
      weights <- eval(weights[[2L]], d, environment(weights))
    }
  }
  type <- match.arg(type)
  if (se.fit || interval != "none") {
    w <- object$weights
    res.var <- if (is.null(scale)) {
      r <- object$residuals
      rss <- sum(if (is.null(w)) r^2 else r^2 * w)
      df <- object$df.residual
      rss/df
    }
    else scale^2
    if (type != "terms") {
      if (p > 0) {
        XRinv <- if (missing(newdata) && is.null(w)) 
          qr.Q(qr.lm(object))[, p1, drop = FALSE]
        else X[, piv] %*% qr.solve(qr.R(qr.lm(object))[p1, 
                                                       p1])
        ip <- drop(XRinv^2 %*% rep(res.var, p))
      }
      else ip <- rep(0, n)
    }
  }
  if (type == "terms") {
    if (!mmDone) {
      mm <- model.matrix(object)
      mmDone <- TRUE
    }
    aa <- attr(mm, "assign")
    ll <- attr(tt, "term.labels")
    hasintercept <- attr(tt, "intercept") > 0L
    if (hasintercept) 
      ll <- c("(Intercept)", ll)
    aaa <- factor(aa, labels = ll)
    asgn <- split(order(aa), aaa)
    if (hasintercept) {
      asgn$"(Intercept)" <- NULL
      if (!mmDone) {
        mm <- model.matrix(object)
        mmDone <- TRUE
      }
      avx <- colMeans(mm)
      termsconst <- sum(avx[piv] * beta[piv])
    }
    nterms <- length(asgn)
    if (nterms > 0) {
      predictor <- matrix(ncol = nterms, nrow = NROW(X))
      dimnames(predictor) <- list(rownames(X), names(asgn))
      if (se.fit || interval != "none") {
        ip <- matrix(ncol = nterms, nrow = NROW(X))
        dimnames(ip) <- list(rownames(X), names(asgn))
        Rinv <- qr.solve(qr.R(qr.lm(object))[p1, p1])
      }
      if (hasintercept) 
        X <- sweep(X, 2L, avx, check.margin = FALSE)
      unpiv <- rep.int(0L, NCOL(X))
      unpiv[piv] <- p1
      for (i in seq.int(1L, nterms, length.out = nterms)) {
        iipiv <- asgn[[i]]
        ii <- unpiv[iipiv]
        iipiv[ii == 0L] <- 0L
        predictor[, i] <- if (any(iipiv > 0L)) 
          X[, iipiv, drop = FALSE] %*% beta[iipiv]
        else 0
        if (se.fit || interval != "none") 
          ip[, i] <- if (any(iipiv > 0L)) 
            as.matrix(X[, iipiv, drop = FALSE] %*% Rinv[ii, 
                                                        , drop = FALSE])^2 %*% rep.int(res.var, 
                                                                                       p)
        else 0
      }
      if (!is.null(terms)) {
        predictor <- predictor[, terms, drop = FALSE]
        if (se.fit) 
          ip <- ip[, terms, drop = FALSE]
      }
    }
    else {
      predictor <- ip <- matrix(0, n, 0L)
    }
    attr(predictor, "constant") <- if (hasintercept) 
      termsconst
    else 0
  }
  if (interval != "none") {
    tfrac <- qt((1 - level)/2, df)
    hwid <- tfrac * switch(interval, confidence = sqrt(ip), 
                           prediction = sqrt(ip + pred.var))
    if (type != "terms") {
      predictor <- cbind(predictor, predictor + hwid %o% 
                           c(1, -1))
      colnames(predictor) <- c("fit", "lwr", "upr")
    }
    else {
      if (!is.null(terms)) 
        hwid <- hwid[, terms, drop = FALSE]
      lwr <- predictor + hwid
      upr <- predictor - hwid
    }
  }
  if (se.fit || interval != "none") {
    se <- sqrt(ip)
    if (type == "terms" && !is.null(terms) && !se.fit) 
      se <- se[, terms, drop = FALSE]
  }
  if (missing(newdata) && !is.null(na.act <- object$na.action)) {
    predictor <- napredict(na.act, predictor)
    if (se.fit) 
      se <- napredict(na.act, se)
  }
  if (type == "terms" && interval != "none") {
    if (missing(newdata) && !is.null(na.act)) {
      lwr <- napredict(na.act, lwr)
      upr <- napredict(na.act, upr)
    }
    list(fit = predictor, se.fit = se, lwr = lwr, upr = upr, 
         df = df, residual.scale = sqrt(res.var))
  }
  else if (se.fit) 
    list(fit = predictor, se.fit = se, df = df, residual.scale = sqrt(res.var))
  else predictor
}
```